# Elasticsearch : _score always 0 in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have this kind of Groovy script:

```
def multiplier = doc['data'].value
if (multiplier <= 0) {
  multiplier = 1
}
multiplier * _score
```

I use it as a `script_score`, and my score is always 0. It seems like `_score` is always 0. With a mvel script, it works.

mvel script was:

```
_score * doc['data'].value
```

Query is (only `lang` changes for the mvel version):

```
"function_score": {
    query: {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                // many matches...
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
        },
    },
    "script_score": {
        "lang": "groovy",
        "file": "my_script",
    },
    "boost": 2.5,
    "score_mode": "max",
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I tested this on Elasticsearch 1.5.2.

Comment: Where did you get the `_score`variable

Comment: @bmscomp ES provides it, it is described in this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: Can you share both mvel and groovy version of the ES queries?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I added the mvel version

Comment: What I meant was both **queries** where you use mvel and groovy, not only the scripts.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I added the query, is it enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a good explanation for this, but this query works for me in Groovy (had to enable logging in the script to see what `_score` is containing):

```
multiplier * _score.score()
```

Comment: @Andrei Stefan, you nailed it. I have been fighting for months with this and my _score always coming back as ZERO. My script was something like this "_score * (some other formula)". I changed to "_score.score() * (some other formula) and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, @Andrei Stefan, how do you enable loggin in the script?

Comment: @Thiago https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-logging-secrets at the bottom of the blog post.